# Subtracting a query result from a table without CURSORs?

Tags: sql-server

I have the result of a `SELECT` statement in the following type of format;

```
ID    Weight
 3        13
12       200
67       505
```

(Not necessarily the exact result, just an example)

Suppose this is some very complicated select query. Now assume there's some table `tbc` which contains 2 columns, say `c1` and `c2`, where I want the value in `Weight` to be subtracted from `c2` wherever `c1` matches `ID`. This is equivalent to executing

```
UPDATE [tbc] SET [c2] = [c2] - 13  WHERE [c1] = 3
UPDATE [tbc] SET [c2] = [c2] - 200 WHERE [c1] = 12
UPDATE [tbc] SET [c2] = [c2] - 505 WHERE [c1] = 67
```

Now, while in a stored procedure, the same effect can be achieved using a `CURSOR` construct;

```
DECLARE @ID int, @Weight int
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR <complicated query> 
OPEN cur1 
FETCH cur1 INTO @ID, @Weight
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN 
    UPDATE [tbc] SET [c2] = [c2] - @Weight WHERE [c1] = @ID
    FETCH cur1 INTO @ID, @Weight
END
CLOSE cur1
DEALLOCATE cur1
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to do this 'more efficiently'. Without using looping/cursor constructs and having to lock up a whole table as well as incur overhead while the updates are happening in a single query. I suppose there are two cases to the question:

Case (1): `<complicated query>` contains a reference to table `tbc` (or a view using this table)

Case (2): `<complicated query>` does not contain a reference to table `tbc`

If a guarantee of uniqueness in either `ID` or `c1` allows for a faster method, I'd like to know this as well, though in the current problem this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your use of the backtick in your query is a carry over from MySQL and only in your post, not your actual query, as I don't believe that is syntactically correct for SQL Server.

Aside from that, you just need a join in your UPDATE statement. I assume the first two columns returned from your query are ID and Weight.

```
WITH (<complicated query>) AS cur1 --Misnomer, but for the sake of example
UPDATE tbc
   SET C2 = tbc.C2 - cur1.Weight
   FROM tbc
      INNER JOIN cur1
         ON C2.ID = cur1.ID
```